# Working with global vars in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How i can use and edit global vars in any place of my module? My project looks like

```
project/
---- models/
---- ---- first.py
---- ---- second.py
---- run.py
```

Run.py is main and i use it ti start app, global vars init in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to `import` them into any other module that you want to use them in. Global variables are only global to the file they're in (unless imported elsewhere).

Note that if you want changes to propagate outside the module you import into, you need to do one of two things:

- Use the non-`from` import syntax (e.g. `import foo.bar` and then `foo.bar = <value>`)
- Use a mutable type and modify it in-place (e.g. a dictionary)

The reason for this is that if you use a `from` import, it creates a local version of the variable that is independent of the one from the other module, but has the same value. For mutable types, this value is a reference, and thus as long as you modify the object in-place, the changes will be visible everywhere (because all the references will point to the same object).

Comment: when i import run.var in first and edit it, in second there are no result

Comment: What's the type of `run.var`? How are you importing it? (Are you using `import run.var` or `from run import var`?) If you're using `from ... import ...`, try switching to `import run.var` and then `run.var = ...`.

Comment: `from run import var` and `var = " "`

Comment: That's your problem, then - when you use `from run import var` you're just getting a copy of the value in a new local variable called `var` - if you want changes to propagate across all instances, you need to either import and work with the original version (`import run.var`) or use a reference type (such as a dictionary or a list) and just modify that item without overwriting it.